# unable to set the Ruby version in RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed the latest RVM, and by default Ruby 1.9.3-p194 was installed.

However, I do not see this Ruby version on the command line:

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ rvm use current
ruby-1.9.3-p194
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$
```

Comment: what version of rvm is it, `rvm use` should warn you that `use` is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not added this line to `.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

After this, setting the Ruby version with RVM succeeds.

Comment: you should enable login shell in your terminal, there is number of known issues with having the sourcing line in *rc files

Answer (score 2):

try

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

or maybe

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

if u want that ruby as a default every time u launch the terminal, also restart the terminal